# Creating a "default constructor" for inner sub-interfaces

Tags: java, constructor, interface, java-8, default

Okay, the title is maybe hard to understand. I didn't find something correct.
So, basically I'm using Java 8 functions to create a Retryable API. I wanted an easy implementation of these interfaces, so I created an `of(...)` method in each implementation of the Retryable interface where we can use lambda expressions, instead of creating manually an anonymous class.

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public interface Retryable<T, R> extends Function<T, R>{

    void retrying(Exception e);

    void skipping(Exception e);

    int trials();

    @Override
    default R apply(T t) {
        int trial = 0;
        while (true) {
            trial++;
            try {
                return action(t);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (trial < trials()) {
                    retrying(e);
                } else {
                    skipping(e);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    R action(T input) throws Exception;

    interface RunnableRetryable extends Retryable<Void, Void> {

        static RunnableRetryable of(Consumer<Exception> retrying, Consumer<Exception> skipping, int trials, CheckedRunnable runnable) {
            return new RunnableRetryable() {
                @Override
                public void retrying(Exception e) {
                    retrying.accept(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void skipping(Exception e) {
                    skipping.accept(e);
                }

                @Override
                public int trials() {
                    return trials;
                }

                @Override
                public Void action(Void v) throws Exception {
                    runnable.tryRun();
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }

        @FunctionalInterface
        interface CheckedRunnable extends Runnable {

            void tryRun() throws Exception;

            @Override
            default void run() {
                try {
                    tryRun();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface ConsumerRetryable<T> extends Retryable<T, Void> {

        static <T> ConsumerRetryable of(Consumer<Exception> retrying, Consumer<Exception> skipping, int trials, CheckedConsumer<T> consumer) {
            return new ConsumerRetryable<T>() {
                @Override
                public void retrying(Exception e) {
                    retrying.accept(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void skipping(Exception e) {
                    skipping.accept(e);
                }

                @Override
                public int trials() {
                    return trials;
                }

                @Override
                public Void action(T t) throws Exception {
                    consumer.tryAccept(t);
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }

        @FunctionalInterface
        interface CheckedConsumer<T> extends Consumer<T> {

            void tryAccept(T t) throws Exception;

            @Override
            default void accept(T t) {
                try {
                    tryAccept(t);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface SupplierRetryable<T> extends Retryable<Void, T> {

        static <T> SupplierRetryable of(Consumer<Exception> retrying, Consumer<Exception> skipping, int trials, CheckedSupplier<T> supplier) {
            return new SupplierRetryable<T>() {
                @Override
                public void retrying(Exception e) {
                    retrying.accept(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void skipping(Exception e) {
                    skipping.accept(e);
                }

                @Override
                public int trials() {
                    return trials;
                }

                @Override
                public T action(Void v) throws Exception {
                    return supplier.tryGet();
                }
            };
        }

        @FunctionalInterface
        interface CheckedSupplier<T> extends Supplier<T> {

            T tryGet() throws Exception;

            @Override
            default T get() {
                try {
                    return tryGet();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface FunctionRetryable<T, R> extends Retryable<T, R> {

        static <T, R> FunctionRetryable of(Consumer<Exception> retrying, Consumer<Exception> skipping, int trials, CheckedFunction<T, R> function) {
            return new FunctionRetryable<T, R>() {
                @Override
                public void retrying(Exception e) {
                    retrying.accept(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void skipping(Exception e) {
                    skipping.accept(e);
                }

                @Override
                public int trials() {
                    return trials;
                }

                @Override
                public R action(T t) throws Exception {
                    return function.tryApply(t);
                }
            };
        }

        @FunctionalInterface
        interface CheckedFunction<T, R> extends Function<T, R> {

            R tryApply(T t) throws Exception;

            @Override
            default R apply(T t) {
                try {
                    return tryApply(t);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But as you can see, there's a lot of duplicate code in every `of(...)` methods. I could create a kind of "constructor" (that's not the correct word, because interfaces can't have a constructor) in the Retryable interface, but I don't know how. Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: I don’t see a reason for these redundant inner interface to exist. You only have multiple factory methods for differently parameterized `Retryable`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is your API explosion. All these nested interfaces extending `Retryable` do not add any functionality, but require the user of this code to deal with them, once they are part of the API. Further, they are the cause of this code duplication, as each of these redundant interfaces requires its own implementation, whereas all implementations are basically doing the same.

After removing these obsolete types, you can simply implement the operations as delegation:

```
public interface Retryable<T, R> extends Function<T, R>{
    void retrying(Exception e);
    void skipping(Exception e);
    int trials();
    @Override default R apply(T t) {
        try { return action(t); }
        catch(Exception e) {
            for(int trial = 1; trial < trials(); trial++) {
                retrying(e);
                try { return action(t); } catch (Exception next) { e=next; }
            }
            skipping(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    R action(T input) throws Exception;

    public static Retryable<Void, Void> of(Consumer<Exception> retrying,
            Consumer<Exception> skipping, int trials, CheckedRunnable runnable) {
        return of(retrying, skipping, trials, x -> { runnable.tryRun(); return null; });
    }

    @FunctionalInterface interface CheckedRunnable extends Runnable {
        void tryRun() throws Exception;
        @Override default void run() {
            try { tryRun(); } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        }
    }

    public static <T> Retryable<T, Void> of(Consumer<Exception> retrying,
            Consumer<Exception> skipping, int trials, CheckedConsumer<T> consumer) {
        return of(retrying, skipping, trials,
                  value -> { consumer.tryAccept(value); return null; });
    }

    @FunctionalInterface interface CheckedConsumer<T> extends Consumer<T> {
        void tryAccept(T t) throws Exception;
        @Override default void accept(T t) {
            try { tryAccept(t); } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        }
    }

    public static <T> Retryable<Void, T> of(Consumer<Exception> retrying,
            Consumer<Exception> skipping, int trials, CheckedSupplier<T> supplier) {
        return of(retrying, skipping, trials, voidArg -> { return supplier.tryGet(); });
    }

    @FunctionalInterface interface CheckedSupplier<T> extends Supplier<T> {
        T tryGet() throws Exception;
        @Override default T get() {
            try { return tryGet(); }
            catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        }
    }

    public static <T, R> Retryable<T, R> of(Consumer<Exception> retrying,
            Consumer<Exception> skipping, int trials, CheckedFunction<T, R> function) {
        return new Retryable<T, R>() {
            @Override public void retrying(Exception e) { retrying.accept(e); }
            @Override public void skipping(Exception e) { skipping.accept(e); }
            @Override public int trials() { return trials; }
            @Override public R action(T t) throws Exception {
                return function.tryApply(t);
            }
        };
    }

    @FunctionalInterface interface CheckedFunction<T, R> extends Function<T, R> {
        R tryApply(T t) throws Exception;
        @Override default R apply(T t) {
            try { return tryApply(t); }
            catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
        }
    }
}
```

There is only one implementation class needed, which has to be able to deal with an argument and a return value, the others can simply delegate to it using an adapter function, doing either, dropping the argument or returning `null`, or both.

For most use cases, the shape of the lambda expression is appropriate to select the right method, e.g.

```
Retryable<Void,Void> r = Retryable.of(e -> {}, e -> {}, 3, () -> {});
Retryable<Void,String> s = Retryable.of(e -> {}, e -> {}, 3, () -> "foo");
Retryable<Integer,Integer> f = Retryable.of(e -> {}, e -> {}, 3, i -> i/0);
```

but sometimes, a little hint is required:

```
// braces required to disambiguate between Function and Consumer
Retryable<String,Void> c = Retryable.of(e->{}, e ->{}, 3,
                                        str -> { System.out.println(str); });
```

Comment: You're totally right. I was looking too far for nothing. Now it's clear. Thanks !

Comment: @Holger we have a retry mechanism also (who doesn't?), but the OP idea of doing it and your answer might give our code a new shape...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can factor some of this out in to a (possibly package-private) abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractRetryable<T, R> implements Retryable<T, R> {
    private final Consumer<Exception> retrying;
    private final Consumer<Exception> skipping;
    private final int                 trials;
    AbstractRetryable(Consumer<Exception> retrying,
                      Consumer<Exception> skipping,
                      int                 trials) {
        this.retrying = Objects.requireNonNull(retrying, "retrying");
        this.skipping = Objects.requireNonNull(skipping, "skipping");
        this.trials   = trials;
    }
    @Override
    public void retrying(Exception x) {
        retrying.accept(x);
    }
    @Override
    public void skipping(Exception x) {
        skipping.accept(x);
    }
    @Override
    public int trials() {
        return trials;
    }
}
```

The only issue with this is that you're using subinterfaces, so you can't create an anonymous class which both extends the abstract class and implements the subinterface.

You could then write more (again, possibly package-private) subclasses:

```
final class RunnableRetryableImpl
extends    AbstractRetryable<Void, Void>
implements RunnableRetryable {
    private final CheckedRunnable runnable;
    RunnableRetryableImpl(Consumer<Exception> retrying,
                          Consumer<Exception> skipping,
                          int                 trials,
                          CheckedRunnable     runnable) {
        super(retrying, skipping, trials);
        this.runnable = Objects.requireNonNull(runnable, "runnable");
    }
    @Override
    public Void apply(Void ignored) {
        try {
            runnable.tryRun();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            // BTW I would consider doing this.
            if (x instanceof RuntimeException)
                throw (RuntimeException) x;
            // I would also probably write a class like:
            // class RethrownException extends RuntimeException {
            //     RethrownException(Exception cause) {
            //         super(cause);
            //     }
            // }
            // This way the caller can catch a specific type if
            // they want to.
            // (See e.g. java.io.UncheckedIOException)
            throw new RuntimeException(x);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Or you could reduce the line count by using local classes:

```
static RunnableRetryable of(Consumer<Exception> retrying,
                            Consumer<Exception> skipping,
                            int                 trials,
                            CheckedRunnable     runnable) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(runnable, "runnable");
    final class RunnableRetryableImpl
    extends    AbstractRetryable<Void, Void>
    implements RunnableRetryable {
        RunnableRetryable() {
            // Avoid explicitly declaring parameters
            // and passing arguments.
            super(retrying, skipping, trials);
        }
        @Override
        public Void apply(Void ignored) {
            try {
               runnable.tryRun();
            } catch (Exception x) {
                if (x instanceof RuntimeException)
                    throw (RuntimeException) x;
                throw new RuntimeException(x);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    return new RunnableRetryableImpl();
}
```

Personally, I think I would just write package-private implementations instead of the local classes but it certainly requires a fair amount of boiler-plate code.

Also, as a side note, when you are writing factories that return anonymous classes, you should use `requireNonNull` inside the method itself (as I did in my example `of` method). This is so that if `null` is passed to the method, the method throws the NPE instead of e.g. some call to `retrying` or `skipping` throwing the NPE some time later.

Comment: Instead of doing an `instanceof` in a `catch` clause, you can simply create a second `catch` clause with that type, e.g. `catch(RuntimeException|Error unchecked) { throw unchecked; } catch(Throwable checked) { throw new RuntimeException(checked); }`